# Cannot recognise Organization in email template?

Tags: email, email-template

Using a VisualForce email template, I try to add:

```
<p>Thank you for your interest in {!Organization.Name}</P>
```

to my template, I get:

```
Error: Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.Organization'
```

Any ideas on how I can get the Organization name in a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with dollar: `{!$Organization.Name}`

In case of problematic field easiest way for me is to start the creator of new formula field or workflow and the editor there works quite nicely, you can always copy over the merge fields from it to the email template, Visualforce page etc.

[Functions reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?language=en&id=customize_functions.htm)

[VF global variables](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_variables_global.htm) (quite a lot of them can be used in emails too)

Comment: Tiny typo in your answer.  You need to do: {!$Organization.Name} but otherwise brilliant it works.  And thanks for the link as well.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, updated. Too eager to answer I guess ;)